# PCI-E, sysfs and user-id permission weirdness

Tags: pci, sysfs

On our 3.X series kernel, a proprietary PCI-Express device has  a proprietary kernel driver. We're seeing some weird errors on trawling PCI capabilities. I can not find any great docs - does anyone know if the kernel driver can control what data is exposed in `sysfs`/`procfs` based on user-id?

Specifically, this call fails inside the vendor's utility:

```
c = pci_find_cap(mdev->pdev, VENDOR_EXT_CAP_ID, PCI_CAP_EXTENDED);
```

After a lot of digging, I can replicate the failure using setpci looking for `VENDOR_EXT_CAP_ID`.

What I'm seeing is:

- FS permissions grant read access to user and root.
- Open the file "config" in `sysfs` and read `$data`.
- `$data` for user vs `$data` for root are different.

I can't see a lot of docs on how this could be possible nor do we have a good escalation path with the Vendor. Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a kernel driver can control the data it exposes in sysfs/procfs based on user-id, and/or basically any information the kernel has access to.

When you read something from procfs or sysfs, the system call for reading the information basically ends calling a function in the respective driver. That function can see all the information on the user-space process that called for the read operation, and can certainly modify its output based on that, or based on anything else the kernel can access.

In the specific case of `/sys/bus/pci/devices/<PCI device ID>/config`, any attempts to read it will end up in [function `pci_read_config()` in file `drivers/pci/pci-sysfs.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/C/ident/pci_read_config) which will check if the calling user-space process has CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability (which in most cases means the user is `root`). If the user does not have that capability, the function will restrict the readable PCI configuration data to the first `(dev->cfg_size)` bytes (128 bytes on CardBus).

In kernel versions 2.6.5 and below, the limit used to be 256 bytes, but in 2.6.6 it was tightened to `(dev->cfg_size)`. On a modern system, the `(dev->cfg_size)` tends to be either 64 or 256 bytes according to the device in question.

You can demonstrate this with a simple `lspci -v`. If you run it as root, you will see the PCI/PCIe capabilities of each device. But if you run it as a regular user, you will get instead:

```
Capabilities: <access denied>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using AlmaLinux 8.8 with a `4.18.0-477.27.2.el8_8.x86_64` Kernel was looking to create a user space application to decode PCIe capabilities as a regular user. For this application wanted to correlate the PCIe link width and speed capabilities of an endpoint against the PCIe root port the endpoint is connected to.

Of the different mechanisms:

1. The `pci_device_cfg_read*` functions from `libpciaccess` fail returning `ENXIO` on attempting to read PCIe capabilities as a regular user without any Linux capabilities given to the executable.

   After using `sudo setcap cap_sys_admin=ep <executable>` was then able to read PCIe capabilities as a regular user.
2. Using `pciutils`:

   - The `pci_read_byte`, `pci_read_word` and `pci_read_long` functions return a value of all-ones on attempting to read PCIs capabilities as a regular user without any Linux capabilities given to the executable. `errno` isn't set upon failure.
   - The `pci_read_block` function returns zero to indicate a failure on attempting to read PCIe capabilities as a regular user without any Linux capabilities given to the executable.

   After using `sudo setcap cap_sys_admin=ep <executable>` was then able to read PCIe capabilities as a regular user.
3. Using [VFIO](https://docs.kernel.org/driver-api/vfio.html), the file descriptor obtained by `VFIO_GROUP_GET_DEVICE_FD` can read PCIe capabilities as a regular user **without** the executable requiring any Linux capabilities to be given to the executable.

   However, the downside of this approach is that VFIO can't be used for PCIe root ports, since the `vfio-pci` driver only binds to a PCI device with a `NORMAL` header type. [vfio_pci_probe](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18/source/drivers/vfio/pci/vfio_pci.c#L1193) contains the following code, which explains the error trying to bind VFIO to a PCIe root port, which has a `BRIDGE` header type:

   ```
    if (pdev->hdr_type != PCI_HEADER_TYPE_NORMAL)
        return -EINVAL;
   ```